# "Undefined symbols for Architecture x86_64 " no templates used, possible syntax error

Tags: c++

I know this is a common question, but please bear with me. From what I understand seeing the past questions:

1. I am not using templates, so something like " template class TreeNode; " before each use of the template, but I am assuming the problem is something similar, related to syntax, or something very basic. If I get this answered I will edit the question so that more people will benefit from it.

So all I have to do is use these code to do some operations in the main.cpp to carry out some operations- e.g. use DeleteItem, Retrieve 10 and print whether found, etc.

the code is as follows:

```
//unsortedtype.h    
#ifndef UNSORTEDTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define UNSORTEDTYPE_H_INCLUDED

#include "itemtype.h"

class UnsortedType
{
    public:
        UnsortedType();
        bool IsFull() const;
        int LengthIs() const;
        void RetrieveItem(ItemType&item, bool&found);
        void InsertItem(ItemType item);
        void DeleteItem(ItemType item);
        void ResetList();
        void GetNextItem(ItemType& item);
        void PrintList();
    private:
        int length;
        ItemType info[MAX_ITEMS];
        int currentPos;
};

#endif // UNSORTEDTYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

//fileno2

```
//unsortedtyoe.cpp
#ifndef UNSORTEDTYPE_CPP_INCLUDED
#define UNSORTEDTYPE_CPP_INCLUDED

#include "unsortedtype.h"

UnsortedType::UnsortedType()
{

    length = 0;
    currentPos = -1;
}

bool UnsortedType::IsFull() const
{

    return (length == MAX_ITEMS);
}

int UnsortedType::LengthIs() const
{

    return length;
}

void UnsortedType::RetrieveItem(ItemType &item, bool &found){
    int location = 0;
    bool moreToSearch = (location < length);
    found = false;
    while (moreToSearch && !found){
        switch (item.ComparedTo(info[location]))
        {
        case LESS:
        case GREATER:
            location++;
            moreToSearch = (location < length);
            break;
        case EQUAL:
            found = true;


        }
    }

}

void UnsortedType::InsertItem(ItemType item)
{

    info[length] = item;
    length++;
}

void UnsortedType::DeleteItem(ItemType item){
    int location = 0;
    while (item.ComparedTo(info[location]) != EQUAL){
        location++;
        info[location] = info[length - 1];
        length++;
            }

}

void UnsortedType::ResetList(){
    currentPos = -1;
}

void UnsortedType::GetNextItem(ItemType &item){
    currentPos++;
    item = info[currentPos];
}

void UnsortedType::PrintList(){
    ItemType it;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++){
        GetNextItem(it);
        it.Print();
        cout<<"";
    }
    ResetList();
    cout<<endl;
}


#endif // UNSORTEDTYPE_CPP_INCLUDED
```

//fileno3

```
//itemtype.h
#ifndef ITEMTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define ITEMTYPE_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_ITEMS = 5;
enum RelationType{LESS, GREATER, EQUAL};

class ItemType{
public:
    ItemType();
    RelationType ComparedTo(ItemType) const;
    void Print() const;
    void Initialize(int number);
private:
    int value;
    } ;

#endif // ITEMTYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

fileno4

```
//itemtype.cpp
#ifndef ITEMTYPE_CPP
#define ITEMTYPE_CPP
#include "itemtype.h"

ItemType::ItemType(){
value = 0;
}

RelationType ItemType::ComparedTo(ItemType otheritem) const
{

    if (value<otheritem.value)
        return LESS;
    else if (value > otherItem.value)
        return GREATER;
    else
        return EQUAL;
}

void ItemType::Initialize(int number){
value = number;
}

void ItemType::Print() const
{

    cout << value << "";
}
#endif // ITEMTYPE_CPP
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "itemtype.h"
#include "unsortedtype.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UnsortedType ustype1;
    cout << ustype1.LengthIs() << endl;
/*
    //insertItem
    ustype1.InsertItem(5);
    ustype1.InsertItem(7);
    ustype1.InsertItem(6);
    ustype1.InsertItem(9);
    ustype1.PrintList();
    ustype1.InsertItem(1);
    ustype1.PrintList();

    //RetreiveItem
    bool found;
    ustype1.RetrieveItem(4, found);
    cout << found << endl;
    ustype1.RetrieveItem(5, found);
    cout << found << endl;
    ustype1.RetrieveItem(9, found);
    cout << found << endl;
    ustype1.RetrieveItem(10, found);
    cout << found << endl;

    //isFULL
    cout << ustype1.IsFull() << endl;
    ustype1.DeleteItem(5);
    cout << ustype1.IsFull() << endl;

    //deleteItem
    ustype1.DeleteItem(1);
    ustype1.PrintList();
    ustype1.DeleteItem(6);
    ustype1.PrintList();


*/
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My first problem is this, when I take out the commented lines in main, and just do IsLength, I get this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/49JMw.png

I think this might be a very basic error, and if you coudl tell me how to resolve this I would be really grateful.

PPS> probably being a little lazy, but when I use the commented out code in Main, I get this error, can someone just quickly tell me how to insert integers into those functions as ItemType?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOhia.png

EDIT: image 1:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in UnsortedList (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++  -o bin/Debug/UnsortedList obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/unsortedtype.o   -lstdc++
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ItemType::ItemType()", referenced from:
      UnsortedType::UnsortedType()in unsortedtype.o
      UnsortedType::UnsortedType()in unsortedtype.o
      UnsortedType::PrintList()      in unsortedtype.o
  "ItemType::ComparedTo(ItemType) const", referenced from:
      UnsortedType::DeleteItem(ItemType)       in unsortedtype.o
      UnsortedType::RetrieveItem(ItemType&, bool&)  in unsortedtype.o
  "ItemType::Print() const", referenced from:
      UnsortedType::PrintList()      in unsortedtype.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: This may not solve it, but remove the include guards from the `.cpp` files. And take some time to think about what include guards do to code :-)

Comment: What is your compiler command-line? Or Makefile?

Comment: Why I should read external links to get the question? And why is the example so big that I can not read it in a short amount of time? I believe you can get a good answer is you post a simplified question which contains all information's **here**.

Comment: I wanted to add images but I needed 10 points to post an image

Comment: Can't you just copy & paste the text. Last I checked, compilers output text, not pictures...

Comment: Ok, I have done it in the question

Comment: Why is `itemtype.o` not included in the compilation?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify itemtype.o on command line like following.

g++ -o bin/Debug/UnsortedList obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/unsortedtype.o obj/Debug/itemtype.o

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify `itemtype.o` while compiling `main()`

```
g++ -o bin/Debug/UnsortedList obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/unsortedtype.o obj/Debug/itemtype.o
```